# Converting an uint64 into a (full)hex string, C++

Tags: c++

I've been trying to get a `uint64` number into a string, in hex format. But it should include zeros. Example:

```
uint i = 1;
std::ostringstream message;
message << "0x" << std::hex << i << std::dec;
...
```

This will generate:

```
0x1
```

But this is not what I want. I want:

```
0x0000000000000001
```

Or however many zeros a `uint64` needs.

Comment: Ramono: This is C++, not visual-c++ which is not a language.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use IO manipulators:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

std::cout << std::setw(16) << std::setfill('0') << std::hex << x;
```

Alternatively, you can change the formatting flags separately on `std::cout` with `std::cout.setf(std::ios::hex)` etc., e.g. [see here ("Formatting")](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios_base/). Beware that the field width has to be set every time, as it only affects the next output operation and then reverts to its default.

To get the true number of hex digits in a platform independent way, you could say something like `sizeof(T) * CHAR_BIT / 4 + (sizeof(T)*CHAR_BIT % 4 == 0 ? 0 : 1)` as the argument for `setw`.

Answer (score 2):

```
message << "0x" << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(12) << std::hex << i << std::dec;
```

And use [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/io/doc/ios_state.html) to save and restore the state of the stream.