# Printing hexadecimal values in C++

Tags: c++, hex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting an uint64 into a (full)hex string, C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6966425/converting-an-uint64-into-a-fullhex-string-c)

I am trying to print the hexadecimal equivalent of an integer in C++,

```
int value=2;
cout<<hex<<value;
```

I am getting 2 as output, i want 0x00000002 as output (i.e. with the non significant zeroes),
can someone please help me out with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is more of a formatting problem. You want to use setw and setfill in addition to hex, since you want a the left padded with 0s and the 0x prefix.

```
cout << "0x" << setw(8) << setfill('0') << right << hex << value;
```

Comment: Don't forget to include `<iomanip>` to get `setw()` and `setfill()`.

Comment: Good point, but if he's using hex, then I'm assuming he already has it included.

Comment: No-argument manipulators are provided by `<iostream>` and others are provided by `<iomanip>`.

Comment: Thanks. I never used them enough to notice that.

Comment: And some standard library include more symbols than they should via include dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the function

```
char *  itoa ( int value, char * str, int base );
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
printf("Ox%08x", value);
```