# printing hash data in hex format with c++

Tags: c++, types, io

I am doing some tests with the xxHash library here: https://github.com/Cyan4973/xxHash

I am having issues with my code below. The hash has been calculated and stored in a class:

```
 uint64_t hash_data = i.get_hash();
 const auto *p = (const unsigned char*) hash_data;
```

When trying to print my hash in a hex format, I cannot get it to work. Could anybody help me figure this out?

I have tried looping over with `sizeof(p)` and `strlen(p)` but all seems to end in a seg fault. Am I correct in thinking that this unsigned char will not have a null terminator?. I have done research on other peoples code, but I still cannot seem to figure out what the simplest way to print this hash as hex.

Comment: Unless this is guaranteed to be a C string, `strlen` does not apply. `sizeof(p)` is the *size of the pointer* not how much data it points to.

Comment: If this is just a 64-bit value then it's simply 8 bytes to iterate over, [usual solutions apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6966425/converting-an-uint64-into-a-fullhex-string-c).

Comment: What makes you believe it's meaningful to cast `hash_data` to a `char*`? That it's actually an address of some text string in memory? You might be looking for `std::cout << std::hex << hash_data;`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik becuase that does not match the xxhash hash format - Example: `C622837617E7C5BB`

Comment: @tadman whenever looping over `*p` in a for loop max 8. I get a seg fault on cout << hex << p[iter]

Comment: Ah. You want `const auto *p = (const unsigned char*) &hash_data;` (note the ampersand), and then walk over 8 bytes. As written, you are not reading 8 bytes of the representation of `hash_data` - you are treating `hash_data` as an address in memory, and trying to read 8 bytes at that address. But of course `hash_data` is not meant to represent a valid address in memory.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik ah yes this is what I had previously but thought it incorrect. When looking at `*p` in the debugger it marks it's value as: `"[\300\f$<5\333\061"` which made me think I was referencing an address rather than the value in `hash_data` - without the `&` the value is seen as correct in the debugger `0x31db353c240cc05b` - when checking the hash with another tool my code is generating it correctly, just can't print it.

Comment: What output do you get from `std::cout << std::hex << hash_data;` then? In what way do you feel it's wrong?

Comment: That bad cast is an example of why C++ recommends using [`static_cast<...>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) for these sorts of operations.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik hmm this seems to be working now, I am not sure what has changed.

Comment: `printf("%llX\n", hash_data);`
I'm not sure to see a need for a pointer if the goal is merely to display the hash value. This can be done from the value itself, and is safer, since walking through the byte representation will result in a different outcome depending on local endianness of the host system.